# What happens when I print a 0,6mm thick wall with a 0,4mm diameter nozzle?

Tags: nozzle

[image]

The wall thickness is 1,2mm but the lip is only 0,6mm thick. How will the 0,4mm nozzle solve this?

Alternatively I could choose a 0,8 mm thick lip, but then the connecting end should be 0,4mm that is too thin.

Comment: Which slicer are you using?

Comment: Nozzle diameter is almost always less than extrusion width.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say you should experiment with [Slic3r](http://slic3r.org/)

it can manage extrusion in very sophisticated way

it can overextrude if you need a line wider than actual nozzle size
as same as it can underextrude if needed
it can even change extrusion continuously while extruding one line

here are simple examples
[image]

[image]

[image]

i use [mattercontrol](http://www.mattercontrol.com/)

take a look here - this is the same object the same layer and the same settings

**please notice - this object has wall thicknes exactly 2 times nozzle diam**

here is what i get with

- native MatterControl slicer engine which gives this slice
  [image]
- and Slic3r engine which gives this slice
  [image]